# Vagrant - Error during 'vagrant up' - Unknown configuration section 'cache'

Tags: macos, configuration, vagrant

I am configuring Vagrant environment on my machine and while firing the 'vagrant up' command, getting the following error:

> Unknown configuration section 'cache'

I tried the steps mentioned at this link:https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/issues/20 but it didn't help.

I am using a Mac with Mavericks and CentOS image virtual box.
Vagrant version - 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.  I found it just by trial and error.  In my Vagrant conf file, I commented the following line and it worked.  Any idea why?

## config.cache.scope = :machine

EDIT - It seems I did not install the Vagrant Cachier plugin. Once I did that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just run -

vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier